# ASP.NET partial class conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net, precompile, partial-classes

Recently in a ASP.NET project i have created an ASPX page and the IDE created the code behind file for me.
I opened that file and see that it's a partial class with the same name of aspx page but with .cs extension (eg: page1.aspx and page1.cs).

After then, i have copied the aspx page, renamed it and started to code a page that is similar to the previous one. I see that when i rename aspx page the .cs file rename accordingly (eg: page2.aspx and page2.cs).

Now i have noticed a mistake that probabily i made during copy paste, in fact both the copied files, even if they have different file name has the same class name.

```
public partial class page1 : System.Web.UI.Page
```

From what i know partial class are a way a programmer could split classes in different files, and this is handy when you have auto-generated code and custom code (developed by a programmer).
So if you would rebuild your auto-generated code the program that do so doesn't mess with programmer code. As far as i know the precompiler take all the files with the same partial class, merge them, and then compile the program.

So given that premises what i am expect is that my error lead to an inconsistency in the ASP.NET program and that incosistency will generate some bug, but this is not the case and i have the feeling that something is wrong in my knowledge (what i have written here about partial classes).
Even if i debug the two pages, seems that the two classes generate two distinguishable instances (not of the same type); in the page load event of one i can not see the protected methods of the other.
This is not what i am expecting, i am expecting two instance of the same type, so one instance should see all methods of both partial file that belong to the same class.

So what i ask is if someone could explain what is wrong in my assumpions, so that i may understand the why of this unexpected bheaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure what you did, duplicated boilerplate code maybe, but if you have to different classes objects is because have different namespaces, if you want to have a single class set same namespace for both and if you want to rename not just the file, go and rename the class

Comment: @SilentTremor : no no i simply create two different file .cs as code behind of two different ASP.NET pages; but with the same partial class name. So i am expecting that the two part of the same partial will "collide"/be merged. I have tested a bit but seems not the case and i don't understand why.

Comment: use same namspace